# TableView Cell Button changes other cell's content

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Upon clicking a button on a specific tableview cell, the button clicks and changes to a check mark. However, other cells change to a check mark as well. And reloading the tableview does not make the check marks disappear. I understand this has to do with reusable cells. But how do I update the cellForRowAtIndex from a method being called upon clicking the cell's button?

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Configure the cell...
    static NSString *ReusableIdentifier = @"Cell";
     SetListTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ReusableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    cell.delegate = self;

    if ([self.selectedRows containsIndex:indexPath.row]) {
    [cell.plusButton setBackgroundImage:checkImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else {
            [cell.plusButton setBackgroundImage:plusImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }


    return cell; 

    }
```

Method in custom cell's class.

```
- (IBAction)addSongButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
[self.delegate addSongButtonPressedOnCell:self];

UIImage *checkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
[self.plusButton setBackgroundImage:checkImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Method from the cell's delegate.

```
-(void)addSongButtonPressedOnCell:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.searchTableView indexPathForCell:sender];
NSMutableDictionary *track = [self.searchTracks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[self.selectedRows addIndex:indexPath.row];


}
```

Comment: You need to show your code for the button click and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, but you cannot rely on the cell to track state - you need to track state in some other data structure and reflect that when you provide the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: The problem with your `IBAction` method is that it doesn't track the selection state anywhere *outside* your button - So when the cell is reused you will have lost the selection state.  You are also unable to restore the selection state when a selected cell comes back into view

Comment: Can you provide an example? @Paulw11

Answer (score 1):

You need to track selection state outside of the cell - the cell is a transient object that displays information from your data model, you can't use it to store state.

Since you have immutable dictionaries for your track data you will need to add an additional data structure to store your selection state.  I would use an `NSMutableSet`.

Add a property to your view controller

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableSet *selectedRows;
```

and initialise it in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.selectedRows=[NSMutableSet new];
```

Then you can use to to track/check selection state -

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Configure the cell...
static NSString *ReusableIdentifier = @"Cell";
SetListTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ReusableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary *track = [self.searchTracks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.searchSongTitle.text = [track objectForKey:@"title"];
cell.searchArtist.text = [[track objectForKey:@"user"]objectForKey:@"username"];

cell.plusButton.tag=indexPath.row;    

if ([self.selectedRows containsIndex:indexPath.row]) {
    [cell.plusButton setBackgroundImage:checkImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {
    [cell.plusButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}



//If there is no picture available. Adds a Custom picture.
if ([[track objectForKey:@"artwork_url"] isEqual:[NSNull null]]){
    cell.searchAlbumArtImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SoundCloudLogo"];
}
else{
    //Init the cell image with the track's artwork.
            UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[track objectForKey:@"artwork_url"]]]];
cell.searchAlbumArtImage.image = cellImage;

            }
return cell; 

}
```

And then your button press handler becomes -

```
- (IBAction)cellAddSongButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSInteger index =  sender.tag;
    [self.selectedRows addIndex:index];
    [sender setBackgroundImage:checkImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

It would be cleaner to create a `Track` class rather than using an `NSDictionary`

Comment: thanks, current code still is showing repeats. I need to use the delegate right? In order to access my locally stored searchTracks.

Comment: Note how my code uses the tag that you put into the button.  You can't use the `sender` to find the cell because `sender` is the button.

Comment: Still not working with tagged index. Also, I'm using NSMutableIndexSet

Comment: Are you still setting the tag on the plus button in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?  It needs to be `indexPath.row`

Comment: You might need to set some breakpoints or add some NSLogs, because the code shown in your question looks OK

Comment: prepareForReuse ended up being the fix.